# segue from allertview

Tags: xcode, ios5, storyboard, segue

I'm stuck wringing to change the view by a segue after the user presses a button in a uiallertview.

This is what i have so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [bericht setEditable:NO];
    [bericht setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];

    if ((internetStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) || (internetStatus == ReachableViaWWAN)){
        dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kJsonURL];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
        });
    } else {

        UIAlertView *geenInternet = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Geen Internet" message:@"Voor het gebruik van deze app is een internet verbinding nodig. Momenteel bent u niet verbonden met het internet. Probeer het later nog eens." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [geenInternet show];

    }

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self preformSegueWithIdentifier:@"geenInternetSegue" sender:self];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Dafaqu?");
    }
}
```

The `[self preformSegueWithIdentifier:@"geenInternetSegue" sender:self];` part doesn't work. anny toughts on how i can fix this?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct method call is:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"geenInternetSegue" sender:self];
```

You flipped the e and the r in perform.